# Failing to set up TOR for command-line use on Mac

Tags: mac, proxy, settings, terminal

I'm failing to make every command in terminal (and ideally every MacOS app) to connect via TOR network by default in MacOS.

A simple test works when I expicitly request to use TOR proxy:

```
curl --socks5 localhost:9050 --socks5-hostname localhost:9050 -s https://check.torproject.org/ | cat | grep -m 1 Congratulations | xargs
Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor.
```

...but fails if I don't specify any proxy at all:

```
$ curl -s https://check.torproject.org/ | cat | grep -m 1 Sorry | xargs
Sorry. You are not using Tor.
```

I'm using VPN set in MacOS System Preferences; I'm on High Sierra 10.13.6.

This is what I've tried to make it work:

- manually adding `Advanced > Socks > Proxies > SOCKS > localhost:9050` to VPN and/or current Internet service (Wi-Fi) for *current* Network Location
- manually creating a full clone of current Network Location and setting it up the same way
- running `. torsocks on` in the Terminal window where I later run `curl`
- running `tor` per se in a separate Terminal window; running `brew services start tor`

Using a [script suggested at kremalicious](https://kremalicious.com/simple-tor-setup-on-mac-os-x) results in:

```
$ INTERFACE=Automatic
$ sudo networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxy $INTERFACE 127.0.0.1 9050 off
Password:
** Error: The parameters were not valid.

$ sudo networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxystate $INTERFACE on
** Error: Unable to find item in network database.
```

Using `torify` results in error:

```
(torify curl -s https://check.torproject.org) | grep Congratulations
ERROR: /usr/bin/curl is located in a directory protected by Apple's System Integrity Protection.
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't mention it, I will suggest you edit your `torrc` configuration file. 
Ideally, you should have a line which looks like this:

```
SocksPort 9050
```

Comment: I just created such file with such a line, it didn't help. And, as I mentioned, if I specify for `curl` which host and port to use as proxy, it works just fine: `curl --socks5 localhost:9050 --socks5-hostname localhost:9050 -s https://check.torproject.org/` => `Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor.`